# Combobox in each row of a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I am making a WPF application that do same work of SSIS, in my next step i want to Mapp my source column to database table columns.
I want to achieve something like this
[image]

Can anyone help me to find a way to bind a combobox to a datagrid.
I am working with MVVM design pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see `ComboBox` when you click by mouse at the `DataGridComboBoxColumn`. Let's see an example:

**Model:**

```
public class Person
{
    public int IdPerson { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    public int IdTeam { get; set; }
    public string NameTeam { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class MainWindowVM
{
    public MainWindowVM()
    {
        LoadData();
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>() {
        new Person() { IdPerson = 1, Name = "Billy" },
        new Person() { IdPerson = 2, Name = "Bobby" },
        new Person() { IdPerson = 2, Name = "Bond" } };

        Teams = new ObservableCollection<Team>() {
        new Team() { IdTeam = 1, NameTeam = "Team A" },
        new Team() { IdTeam = 2, NameTeam = "Team B" },
        new Team() { IdTeam = 3, NameTeam = "Team C" } };
    }


    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }
}
```

}

**View:**

```
<Window x:Class="WPFApplication.MainWindow"
        ...the code omitted for the brevity
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WPFApplication.ViewModel"
        Title="a" Height="350" Width="525" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowVM/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" />

                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="CourtType"
                                            DisplayMemberPath="NameTeam" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding IdTeam}" SelectedValuePath="{Binding IdTeam}"
                                            >
                        <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.Teams}"/>
                                <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.Teams}"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>                
            </DataGrid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: i know that there is a component DataGridComboBoxColumn, but my question is ! how can i fill the combobox with items from database

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionForDatagrid}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="InputColumn">
             <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                     <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionForComboBox}" />
                  </DataTemplate>
             </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```